# Auto click em botão com o Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, click, tampermonkey

Tenho um botão em um site, que serve para agradecer, gostaria de saber como fazer um script para o Tampermonkey, e que quando a página seja carregada, ele execute essa função de <kbd>**click**</kbd> nesse botão, tendo como base o `class` `thank_user`.

Agradecer

Isso só deve ser executado em uma certa url.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teste isso :

```
$('.thank_user').click();
```

A url pode ser configurada direto no tampermonkey na linha `@Match`.